# Best way to test & experiment with nginx, apache?

Tags: apache, nginx, virtual-machine, vps, sandbox

What's the best way to experiment with local installations of web servers, like nginx and apache, in such a way that it's easy to discard and start a new instance of either? I'm new to both of these server technologies, and I'm doing a lot of tweaking to familiarize myself with each. As a consequence, I frequently mess up my rigs and find myself having to retrace my steps, or worse, uproot and re-install the darn things entirely.

What's the best "sandbox"-type solution for this? virtual machines? local VPSs? a liveUSB image that I can easily overwrite and start over?

Thanks!

Comment: Most people would use virtual machines for this sort of thing. Are you having a specific programming problem here?

Comment: Hey @GregHewgill, thanks. Yeah - I'm trying to get nginx running for a flask app, but I'm having a bumpy ride following [this tut](http://blog.kramerapps.com/post/22551999777/flask-uwsgi-nginx-ubuntu). As for a dev VM, is [this](http://blogroids.com/2012/02/build-a-development-server-virtual-machine-for-django-with-virtualenv-nginx-uwsgi-and-centos-2/) similar to what you're talking about? Thanks again.

Comment: And to the world at large: Is this what Vagrant is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use (a) separate config-file(s). In case of apache2 on linux, copy /etc/apache2/ to /etc/apache2b/, in /etc/apache2b/sites-available/default change

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

to something like

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
```

and start the 2nd apache with

```
apache2 -f /etc/apache2b/apache2.conf
```